# How to pass json array to postgresql function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a json object contains array of json.

i.e:

```
{
    ID:'1',
    Name:'Pooja',
    School:[{Name:'ABC',Address:'Nagpur'},{Name:'CDF'},{Name:'GHI',Year:{From:'2015',To:'2016'}}]
}
```

I want to insert this in three different table as User, School and Year.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I understood you correctly, you want to split the provided JSON object and write its subobjects to some tables.

PostgreSQL has several JSON operators that might help.

First of all, you should cast JSON's textual representation to type `json`. This allows you to use JSON operators and functions, such as **`->`** (Get JSON object field):

```
select
'{
   "ID":1,
   "Name":"Pooja",
   "School":[
      {
         "Name":"ABC",
         "Address":"Nagpur"
      },
      {
         "Name":"CDF"
      },
      {
         "Name":"GHI",
         "Year":{
            "From":"2015",
            "To":"2016"
         }
      }
   ]
}'::json -> 'Name';

 ?column? 
----------
 Pooja
(1 row)
```

Or, for example, **`#>`** (Get JSON object at specified path):

```
select 'YOUR_JSON'::json #> '{"School", 2, "Year"}';

          ?column?          
----------------------------
 {                         +
             "From":"2015",+
             "To":"2016"   +
          }
(1 row)
```

All you have to do now is insert the result of the operator application into the table of your choice:

```
insert into user select 'YOUR_JSON'::json -> 'Name';
```

If you simply want to extract the **School** array, you could still use **`->`** operator:

```
select 'YOUR_JSON'::json -> 'School';

          ?column?           
-----------------------------
 [                          +
       {                    +
          "Name":"ABC",     +
          "Address":"Nagpur"+
       },                   +
       {                    +
          "Name":"CDF"      +
       },                   +
       {                    +
          "Name":"GHI",     +
          "Year":{          +
             "From":"2015", +
             "To":"2016"    +
          }                 +
       }                    +
    ]
(1 row)
```

Read the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) for more.

Comment: Thank you, I feel it will help me better.

Comment: Thank you, My Problem is solved now. I have to add some more function in it . But it is in work now.